# Query that excludes rows in a certain table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `users`, `contacts`, and `groups`. I want to find all the contacts of a user, and then from those selected contacts, I want to exclude those contacts of that user that have a particular `group_id` found in the `groups` table.

My `groups` table is structured as such:

```
id (primary key)
group_id (a foreign key to a table contain general group info)
user_id (a foreign key to the users table)
```

My `contacts` table is structured like this:

```
id (primary key)
user_id (a foreign key to the `users` table of the user who added the contact)
contact_id (a foreign key to the `users` table of the added contact)
```

My current, not-working query is this:

```
"""SELECT c.*, u.*
   FROM contacts c
       LEFT JOIN groups g ON c.contact_id = g.user_id
       INNER JOIN users u on u.id = c.contact_id
   WHERE c.user_id = %s AND
       <not sure what further constraints to place on query>""", (user_id, group_id)
```

From my understanding, the `LEFT JOIN` is certainly incorrect, and given that it is incorrect, I have not yet added any more constraints in the `WHERE` clause.

What is the best way to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: Where/how do you link a user to a group ? You most probably need to include that table in your query's join clause...

Comment: Well, in this current attempt, I was...tentatively doing the ON c.contact_id = g.user_id. Granted, I know this is not correct. I'll keep working at it, but I'm not exactly sure what direction to work towards, so to speak.

Comment: Any reason you are doing `u.id = c.contact_id` in both your `ON` and `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: No there is not. My fault. Removed accordingly.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` implies that you want to include contacts that do not belong to a group.  Is this correct?

Comment: Well...sort of. My goal is to exclude any of the user's contacts who are in a particular group, and hence, are associated with a particular group id. For example, a user has 10 contacts. He added 4 to a group. I want to query to get the remaining 6 – none of whom can be in that particular group of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `LEFT JOIN` is correct and you want to include contacts who do not belong to any group, you can try the following query:

```
select 
    c.*,
    u.*
from users u
    join contacts c
        on u.id = c.user_id
    left join groups g
        on c.contact_id = g.user_id
where
    c.user_id = %s
    and g.group_id not in (<your groups here>)
```

Where your list of groups would be a comma-separated list of identifiers.  I don't know if the PostgreSQL python driver contains any function for easily formatting this or not, but that is the idea.

To answer your secondary question in your comment (how to get contacts without group AND contacts in excluded group), you probably need to use a union:

```
select 
    c.*,
    u.*
from users u
    join contacts c
        on u.id = c.user_id
    left join groups g
        on c.contact_id = g.user_id
where
    c.user_id = %s
    and g.group_id is null
union
select 
    c.*,
    u.*
from users u
    join contacts c
        on u.id = c.user_id
    join groups g
        on c.contact_id = g.user_id
where
    c.user_id = %s
    and g.group_id = %d
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, and the NOT IN clause works nicely. However, how would I include those contacts who do not belong to any group (and thus, are not in the groups table), as well as those who do belong to the particular group I would like to exclude - note, this latter part works perfectly.

Comment: My apologies. I mistyped. Please see my amended comment (...as well as those who do *not* belong to the particular group I would like to exclude) Thank you for your answer. With its help I was able to figure out what I needed to do.